# JSON data type for like column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make  `like` column.

`like` column is used when users like the content they push like button and users can do 1 like for 1 content.

So I decided to use JSON data type for `like` in order to prevent duplication of like.

but, here is my problem: I've read document, functions are seemed to be required original data as first parameter.

ex:)

```
mysql> SET @j = '{"a": 1}'; //this is original data
mysql> SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@j, '$', 'z') as result;
+---------------------------------+
| result                          |
+---------------------------------+
| [{"a": 1}, "z"]                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

If I want to add `{"b":2}` then I need to fetch all json data, all I want to do is just push a data to it not fetching all json data from `like` column.

I want to do this :

```
mysql> SELECT database.table.`like`.JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('$', '{"b":2}') as result;
+---------------------------------+
| result                          |
+---------------------------------+
| [{"a": 1}, "z"]                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@JillAndMe! you can use the JSON_ARRAY_APPEND() method. I hope this will help you [JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()](https://database.guide/json_array_append-append-values-to-a-json-array-in-mysql/)